# Internationalization with {% trans %} block

Tags: python, django, internationalization, web

I am trying to do a simple example in order to understand Django internationalization.

From what I've been reading in the djangoproject documentation, the simplest way to do it is to wrap the you want to be translated from the template with a `{% trans %}` block.

From what I understood and had expected, was for the translation to be executed automatically for the string, in my case:

```
{% for x in found_bills %}
    <tr>
        <td>{% trans x.name %}
    </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and for the string in x.name (it's a day's name, in English, i.e. "sunday") to be translated and returned to the template where it was dispalyed in its translated form.

Did I misunderstand the way it works?

**UPDATE:**

Error: errors happened while running xgettext on _argparse.py
./build/ipython/IPython/external/argparse/_argparse.py:1113: warning: 'msgid' format string with unnamed arguments cannot be properly localized:
                                                                      The translator cannot reorder the arguments.
                                                                      Please consider using a format string with named arguments,
                                                                      and a mapping instead of a tuple for the arguments.

**SECOND UPDATE:**

HTML code from template is the one above, and the following code is the one in the view.

***bills.py:***

```
def bills(request):
    bills = ps_bill.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('bills.html',"bills":bills,},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Django, but I can assure you it won't automatically translate it. This will probably just mark it for translation.

Comment: I too thought the same thing. http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/14/multi-language-support-in-a-django-project/
http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter19/
Should get you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internationalization and localization are complex, and there's no substitute for [reading the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/). But here's a very rough outline of the necessary steps:

1. You need to mark up all strings requiring translation. In templates you use [`{% trans "text" %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) for simple cases, and [`{% blocktrans %} text {% endblocktrans %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) for complex cases. In source code you wrap strings with [the `ugettext` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code) (or one of its variants). In Django 1.4, you can also [localize URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-url-patterns).
2. Run [the `makemessages` administration command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files) to create a message file for each language you want to translate into.
3. Translate the messages into your target languages. You can do this in your text editor, but you may want to use computer-assisted translation tools to help with at this step: [see Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation#Some_notable_CAT_tools) for a partial list of tools that work with GNU message files (`.po` extension). If you have translators, talk to them and find out what software they prefer to use.
4. Run [the `compilemessages` administration command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#compiling-message-files) to compile the message files.
5. Turn on Django's [language preference detection middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference). If your site has registered users, give them a language preference setting. For non-logged-in users, provide a way to switch language (either by URL or by language preference cookie.)

Oh, and read the documentation.

Comment: And if the .po files that should have been created by the `makemessages` command aren't there, what can I do? Is there a template for a .po file?

Comment: You should figure out why the `.po` files are missing. Perhaps `makemessages` couldn't find any messages? What does it say when you pass the `-v 2` argument?

Comment: I've read that the `makemessages` command implicitly searches the `.html` files for translation blocks. I have my templates in a `templates` folder in my root folder. I started to run the command in my application folder, where I set the locale, but no `.po` files   were created. I then moved up and ran the `makemessages` command in the root folder, but then I get some errors related to a certain `build` folder created by my virtual environment. So, that's my issue now, and the one I have to fix for everything to work, I think.

Comment: You may find the `--ignore` option to `makemessages` useful.

Comment: `django-admin.py makemessages -l en --ignore build/` still throws errors.

Comment: You're not exactly giving me much to go on!

Comment: I've updated the post with the error it throws when running the `django-admin.py makemessages -l en --ignore build/` command

Comment: Clearly `--ignore build/` is not matching your `build` directory. Try `--ignore ./build` instead?

Comment: Did that too, still no success. I decided to delete the directory, hopefully it won't break anything, though I feel in the future there might be some problems. Anyway, now I managed to make the program create the .po and .mo files, which work for static text, but for variables, well, that's where my problem is. I've read that `{% trans %}` should work with variables too, but in my case it seems it doesn't. I will post the HTML code of where I'm printing the variables, and the view which sends the values to the template.

Comment: The length of this comment thread suggests that it's time to close out this question and ask a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#localization-how-to-create-language-files) through. `trans` tag just marks string for translation, as the doc says:

> Once the string literals of an application have been tagged for later
>   translation, the translation themselves need to be written (or
>   obtained).... The first step is to create a message po. file for a new
>   language ... then it's your responsibility to change the po files (by putting the language-specific translation in it)... finally you need to use tools to run over all available .po files and
>   creates .mo files... (after that) your translations are ready for use.

Comment: Ok, thank you. As soon as I will do this, it it turns out to work I will mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but better than never. I came across the same error, actually I had Ipython installed in me virtualenv named env/. As I wanted to translate my project, not the packages under env/ my solution was to do the following:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l LL --ignore=env/* (EDITED)
```

where LL is the name you are giving to your translation.

Hope someone finds it useful since this error can be frustrating, it's a bad formatted string in the source of IPython package.

Cheers !